# type: typeof variable vs type: string

Tags: typescript

got warn message when i build react redux app:

> "message": "Type '{ type: string; payload: Text[]; }' is not assignable to type 'MessageAction'.\n  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.\n    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '\"MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS\"'.",

So:

what is the different 1 and 2 in src/pages/home/modules/types.ts

```
// src/pages/home/modules/types.ts
1. got warn msg
export const MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS = "MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS"

export interface MessageAction {
  type: typeof MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS
  payload: Text[]
}

2.no warn msg
export const MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS = "MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS"

export interface MessageAction {
  type: string
  payload: Text[]
}
```

```
// src/pages/home/modules/actions.ts
import { Dispatch } from "redux"

import { MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS, MessageAction } from "./types"

export const loadMessageData = () => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch
): Promise<MessageAction> => {
  const messages: Text[] = await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve([{ text: "home ~~~~~~" }]))
  })

  return dispatch({
    type: MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS,
    payload: messages
  })
}
```

more info code repo is 
https://github.com/77xi/SSR/pull/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the code you provided to create a slightly simpler failure case:

```js
const MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS = "MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS";

interface MessageActionOne {
  type: typeof MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS;
  payload: Text[];
}

interface MessageActionTwo {
  type: string;
  payload: Text[];
}

// Infered type will be: { type: string; payload: never[]; }
const action = {
  type: MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS,
  payload: []
};

const one: MessageActionOne = action;
//    ^^^  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS"'
```

[Here is the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgUQMpIIIHFkH1UGEAqAkgPIBySWSAqrrskjALwwBEiKG2eRZF1t9FgG4AUCICWYKAFMATgDMAhsGnxpECIoDm01MCjjwxMKoDeImDCgBPAA7SAXFbvSQ8+PU4VuJcpRp0KKKWtorWADYgigAmTvjSAB5QANoAuqIAvmKSMgrKqnDqmjp6BuD4AO4gMOaWNvZO0LKSWsEwoRFRsTDxSWmZYgD0gzCEYPJy0tHO9jAV4uHhMABGjjUza00tQu1hkTFOJgBucv0wWaCQsMplYEw1FhtO7GiY3gS+fAH0ADSPHftumkRBlRCJLtAYOA1oUNNpdPpDGBjKpmDckaJhpZLAA9PGWfAuGAAci2YC0xJg4ggMDAIGuGnEWjAimW4VUUGq9VUxLYnjeOA+vH8AhQLGJQA)

The issue is that in this example `action` is being infered as `type: string` and not `type: "MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS"`.

If you updated the first line with `as const` that should resolve this typing issue:

```js
const MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS = "MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS" as const;

interface MessageActionOne {
  type: typeof MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS;
  payload: Text[];
}

interface MessageActionTwo {
  type: string;
  payload: Text[];
}

// Infered type will be: { type: "MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS"; payload: never[]; }
const action = {
  type: MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS,
  payload: []
};

const one: MessageActionOne = action;
```

[Here is the TypeScript playground for the fixed example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgUQMpIIIHFkH1UGEAqAkgPIBySWSAqrrskjALwwBEiKG2eRZF1t9FjACGEGKEhQA3ACgZASzBQApgCcAZsODL4yiBGEBzZamBR54YmB0BvGTBhQAngAdlALkevlIdfHqcFNwk5JQ0dCiyDi7CTgA2IMIAJp74ygAeUADaALqyAL5yiioaWjpwegbGpubg+ADuIDB2Ds5untCqioZRMDHxiSkwaZm5BXIA9BMwhGDqaspJXm4w9fJxcTAARh7Ny7tsAZhBBCF84YJSfbEJyZ7WAG5qYzCFEtAiZhZgTM32+552GhjjhTrwwgIUAAaf79W5DXIyfKyGTvWDgXYVfRGExfSzWX5aWpgKRAA).

`const` assertions were added in TypeScript 3.4 and [you can read more here about them](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). The first problem highlighted is the one you're running into:

> no literal types in that expression should be widened (e.g. no going from "hello" to string)

Comment: export const MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS: string = "MESSAGES_ACTIONS_SUCCESS" can also resolve this issue

Comment: Yes, but then you're losing out on some of the type safety.

Comment: also get lint err Type string trivially inferred from a string literal, remove type annotation  @typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types